# Why is my debugger skipping Console.ReadLine()?

Tags: c#, debugging

So, I've been debugging my program for several hours, bashing my head against a problem that now seems to occur somewhere else due to one line of code not being correctly executed.

```
#if !DEBUG
            ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new CommunicationManager() };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
#else
            CommunicationManager cm = new CommunicationManager();
            cm.StartService();
            Console.WriteLine("CommunicationService debug");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            cm.StopThreadsAndQueues();
#endif
```

it is supposed to stop at the `Console.ReadLine()` to keep the debug window open until a key is pressed. but since the `cm.StopThreadsAndQueues();` code is executed regardless the program eventually dies even if the thread I'm looking at to debug an errant code is still running :P

Comment: What happens exactly if you go through the code step by step?

Comment: If you step through this code in your debugger can you confirm firstly that it is going into the second part of the code (ie your DEBUG symbol is working as expected) and does it definitely not run the `Console.ReadLine()`? Does it write the line before it for example? Can you put a writeline in after to confirm that it is definitely going past that line rather than for example crashing?

Comment: s is null after that line is executed

Comment: How do you know the `ReadLine` call didn't wait? It could very well be that someone is writing to your input stream. How do you run the application?

Comment: Does your service start correctly ? Or is it actually throwing an exception?

Comment: Looks like the Main() method of a service.  A service doesn't have a console.  Project > Properties > Application tab > Output type > change it to Console Application.  Good enough to debug, not to actually run as a service.  You'd have to pinvoke AllocConsole() if you want to do both.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, this solved my problem. it was setup as a windows application, not console application.